# data structure of objects and methods in c#

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, data-structures

I am new to c# and fairly new to programming. I need help with a topic which i have been trying to figure out from the past week. I have 3 files:

1. Control: this is an interface and should contain the list of my
   methods
2. ControlImpl : this the implementaion of the interfaces.
3. Runtime: contains which the binding code between the main method
   and the interface implementaion
4. Test_main: from where i call the
   runtime method 'call'

**Problem**: there can be any number of instances(for ex: c, c1, c2, etc) in Control file and each instance should be able to call SetTime() and Nop() methods.

I made a list of the methods `SetTime()` and `Nop()`. But how can i add the instance to a list so that each instance when called should call its methods?

CONTROL

```
namespace create_interface
{
 interface Control
 {

    void SetTime(params object[] paramsArr);
    void Nop(params object[] paramsArr);
}

public class CM
{
    Control c = new ControlImpl();
    public List<object> ControlMain()
    {


        List<object> methods = new List<object>();
        methods.Add(new Action<object[]>(c.SetTime));                                
        methods.Add(new Action<object[]>(c.Nop));                    
        return methods;
    }

}

}
```

ControlImpl :

```
 namespace create_interface
 {
   public class ControlImpl : Control
   {
    void Control.SetTime(params object[] paramsArr)                       
    {
        Console.WriteLine("inside Control.SetTime {0} ", paramsArr[0]);

    }

    void Control.Nop(params object[] paramsArr)                      
    {
        Console.WriteLine("inside Control.Nop ");

    }
    }
 }
```

Runtime:

```
 namespace create_interface
  {

public class runtime
{
 public void call(params object[] methodparams)
    {


        if ((methodparams[0].Equals(0)) || (methodparams[0].Equals(1)))
        {
            //List<Control> objectlists = cmObject.ControlObjectList();

            List<object> methods = cmObject.ControlMain();
            //Console.WriteLine(methods.Count);
            Action<object[]> method = (Action<object[]>)methods[(int)methodparams[0]];        //object[]
            object[] args = new object[] { methodparams[1] };
            method(args);
       }            

        else
            Console.WriteLine("wrong ID number entered");
    }
```

Test_main:

```
namespace create_interface
{
  class test_main
  {

     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        long time;
        CallingFunc CF = new CallingFunc();


        Console.WriteLine("enter method ID");
        int methodID = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        try
        {
            switch (methodID)
            {
                case 0:
                    Console.WriteLine("enter the time in long");
                    time = Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine());
                    CF.call(methodID, time);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    CF.call(methodID, null);
                    break;

               default:
                    Console.WriteLine("you entered wrong method ID or parameters");
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
   }
```

Comment: Do you mean having a list with all your instances to execute a given method on all of them at the same time? If so, take a look at the List<T> object in the System.Collection.Generics namespace.

Comment: @NahuelIanni the Test_main should contain  Runtime.call(ID); So a ID is passed to runtime-> call method which should link to the respective instance(ie; c, c1, c2,etc) and to the respective method(ie; SetTime or Nop).

Comment: @NahuelIanni So i was thinking it should need something like a tree. A tree which consists of instances and these instances should be linked to the method. But, i am not sure if this is the correct procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the following solution and we can use it as a base to come up with your final solution:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow38200633
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Collection<IControl> controls = new Collection<IControl>();
            controls.Add(ControlFactory.Create());
            controls.Add(ControlFactory.Create());
            controls.Add(ControlFactory.Create());

            ControlManager manager = new ControlManager(controls);

            Console.WriteLine("Enter method ID:");
            int methodID = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            try
            {
                switch(methodID)
                {
                    case 0:
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter the time in long: ");
                        long time = Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine());
                        manager.InvokeAllSetTime(time);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        manager.InvokeAllNop();
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("You entered wrong method ID or parameters");
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public interface IControl
    {
        void SetTime(long time);
        void Nop();
    }

    public class ConcreteControl : IControl
    {
        public void SetTime(long time)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("inside Control.SetTime {0} ", time);
        }
        public void Nop()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("inside Control.Nop ");
        }
    }

    public class ControlManager
    {
        public void InvokeAllSetTime(long time)
        {
            foreach(IControl control in _controls) control.SetTime(time);
        }
        public void InvokeAllNop()
        {
            foreach(IControl control in _controls) control.Nop();
        }
        public ControlManager(Collection<IControl> controls)
        {
            _controls = controls;
        }
        public Collection<IControl> _controls { get; private set; }
    }

    public static class ControlFactory
    {
        public static IControl Create()
        {
            return new ConcreteControl();
        }
    }
}
```